# when we run the hello-world image its throws the connection refused error message

Tags: docker

Am newly started learning the docker concepts and i have installed the docker latest version on my VM as per docker official docs, but when i execute the "sudo docker run hello-world" command am getting the below error message.

Error message:
sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: http: error connecting to proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3128: getsockopt: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.

Note: I have modified the docker file on /etc/default/docker and enabled the proxy setting as well.
Docker file:

## If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.

export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

please find below output as when i execute the "route" command on my VM.

$route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0

please give your valuable comments on this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you paste the output of 
`$ ps -ef | grep docker`

Comment: Thanks sohan for your prompt response. please have a look into above command output.  $ ps -ef | grep docker
root      3636     1  0 10:52 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/dockerd --raw-logs
root      3648  3636  0 10:52 ?        00:00:02 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
rajasek+  3899  2918  0 11:20 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker

Comment: I can see docker daemon is not started correctly, it is not listening on port your are trying to access.
Is this image built on your local machine or you are trying to pull from dockerhub?

Comment: pulling from dockerhub only. Actually i have followed the below doc for learning the docker. https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: what version of OS you are uisng, are you starting docker as service?

Comment: $ uname -a
Linux raja-VirtualBox 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
raja@raja-VirtualBox:/etc/default$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

Comment: I assume you have followed following installation https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: yes, i have followed the same doc.

Comment: Did you tried export HTTP_PROXY="http://<your_Ip>:3128/" instead of localhost

Comment: Yes, please find below o/p for the same.  $ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:e3:5f:6f:79  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: $ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: http: error connecting to proxy http://172.17.0.1:3128/: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:3128: getsockopt: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: If you are behind some proxy on VM then probably it will stop connecting , set http_proxy="" and then disable firewall on ubuntu. This should work

Comment: Okay, so can i set back to http_proxy to localhost and disable firewall on ubuntu? can i execute the "sudo ufw disable" for disable firewall on ubuntu? is this fix my issue.

Comment: No luck. still am facing same issue. $ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: http: error connecting to proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3128: getsockopt: connection refused.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: if proxy is set to empty, still from where it is reading the proxy? Paste the output of your /etc/default/docker

Comment: I found this link similar to your issue, make sure you have done it proper way as it is most common issue. https://forums.docker.com/t/beginner-having-trouble-with-docker-behind-company-proxy/3968/9 and i guess you have posted there as well :)

Comment: Yes sohan, i have already posted my quety on docker support but no response. # Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.

export HTTP_PROXY="http://172.17.0.1:3128/"